# Android Facebook Handle Session

Tags: android, facebook, session, button, authentication

I am trying to get the username and the userid of my facebook account, using the facebook sdk for android, I am using this snippet of code:

```
final Session session = Session.getActiveSession();
    if (session != null && session.isOpened()) {
        // If the session is open, make an API call to get user data
        // and define a new callback to handle the response
        Request request = Request.newMeRequest(session, new Request.GraphUserCallback() {
            @Override
            public void onCompleted(GraphUser user, Response response) {
                // If the response is successful
                if (session == Session.getActiveSession()) {
                    if (user != null) {
                        user_ID = user.getId();//user id
                        profileName = user.getName();//user's profile name
                        userNameView.setText(user.getName());
                    }   
                }   
            }   
        }); 
        Request.executeBatchAsync(request);
    }
```

The problem is that session is null, how should I handle the session managament? I mean which code to active a session and which code to deactivate the session ? **I want to handle the session to facebook myself using my own buttons of exit and login**, but don't find the code to manage the session.

Thanks alot in advance !

Answer (score 1):

Your `Session.getActiveSession()` is `null` beacuse you haven't initialized a session properly.
Take a look at the code below:

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity {

private UiLifecycleHelper uiHelper;
    private Session.StatusCallback callback = new Session.StatusCallback() {
        @Override
        public void call(final Session session, final SessionState state, final Exception exception) {
        /** If your session status has changed you can dead with that using this callback. */
       }
    };

@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
       // Your code goes here

       /* Initializing a valid session. */
       uiHelper = new UiLifecycleHelper(this, callback); //callback can be null
       uiHelper.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

       Settings.addLoggingBehavior(LoggingBehavior.INCLUDE_ACCESS_TOKENS);
    }

@Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
      super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
      uiHelper.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);}
    }

@Override
    protected void onPause() {
     super.onPause();
     uiHelper.onPause();
    }

@Override
    protected void onStop() {
     super.onStop();
     Session.getActiveSession().removeCallback(callback);
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
     uiHelper.onDestroy();
    }
}
```

Let me know if this was usefull to you.

Comment: So I need to use the UiLifecycleHelper to handle the session of facebook?

Comment: @DarkLink, Yes! Take a look at the Facebook open source SDK and you will realize that `UiLifecycleHelper` creates a new session.

Comment: And what does the method onActivityResult ?

Comment: @DarkLink, `onActivityResult` makes sure you receive callback when clicking the permission dialogs, e.g.